# VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses::AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am porting over a Flex application from 4.1 to 4.5 and have run into some issues with the AdvancedDataGrid classes being found.  The application compiles ok under 4.5.1 but at runtime I get the following error:

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses::AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider could not be found.

It appears that what was the old datavisualization.swc was divided into to libraries (advancedgrids_4.5.21328.swf and charts_4.5.21328.swf) both of which are present in my project. is there anything in the configuration that I need to update?

I am currently using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Helios Service Release 1)

Many thanks,

Ian

Comment: That is unexpected; can you provide the full runtime error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Verify error really means that there's something wrong with versions of classes you are trying to access at runtime. 
First of all, you can try plaing with 'merged/rsl' settings. Second, you can double-check your includes or try to build your app outside ide, with ant task, for example.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the responses,  I'm not sure I can get the full stack trace on a post,  but I can e-mail it if that'll help.

Comment: It may be better if you export your project to .fxp and upload to some file sharing resource, and then update your question with a link. However, did you try to compile your project with sdk included as rsls, not as 'merged into code'?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to merge your libraries into code. This might be helpful -

[VerifyError: Error #1014: class could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019471/verifyerror-error-1014-class-could-not-be-found)